# How to wrap a row value in the treeview table output using Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

[the treeview output without wrapping and editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrQGL.png)I need to wrap a row value in the treeview widget. I have added a sample code below which can reproduce my issue. The value in the first column "Attributes" should be wrapped into multiple lines rather than getting the row value in one single sentence. due to this the readability is affected. Also, is it possible to make these rows editable to add our own text?  the second-row value of the first column (Attributes) asks to edit it. Is it possible to make rows editable in the treeview? please note that currently I have tree view rows values as  a list of lists stored in a variable in order to be inserted into the treeview. But for the demonstration purposes in the below code, the values are manually given.

The first-row value of column 1 needs to be wrapped into multiple lines. Need to make the second-row value of column 1 editable. ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrQGL.png)

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root= Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview", highlightthickness=0, bd=0, font=('Calibri', 11)) # Modify the font of the body
style.configure("mystyle.Treeview.Heading", font=('Calibri', 13,'bold')) # Modify the font of the headings
style.layout("mystyle.Treeview", [('mystyle.Treeview.treearea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]) # Remove the borders
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,style="mystyle.Treeview")  # this is the treeview widget to display the dataframe
column_list_account = ["ATTRIBUTE", "VALUE"]  # These are the headings
tree['columns'] = column_list_account  # We assign the column list to the widgets columns
tree["show"] = "headings"  # this hides the default column
for column in column_list_account:  # for each column
    tree.heading(column, text=column)  # let the column heading =column name
    tree.column(column, width=100, stretch =YES)  # set the column size to 50px
    tree.place(relheight=1,
                relwidth=1)  # set the height and width of the widget to 100% of its container (self.frame1)
treescroll = tk.Scrollbar(root)  # create a scrollbar
treescroll.configure(command=tree.yview)  # make it vertical
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=treescroll.set)  # assign the scrollbar to the Treeview Widget
treescroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")  # make the scrollbar fill the yaxis of the Treeview widget

tree.insert("", "end", values=("Observation_Number ():when the system identidies the keyword is Observation_Number, it will convert the current observation number to character and assign to the target variable.", "Normal"))  # inserts each list into the treeview
tree.insert("", "end", values =("Edit me", "Is it possible to edit me as well?"))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide us an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can reproduce the problem

Comment: Please reduce this code down to a [mcve]. There is a whole lot of code that is unnecessary to reproduce the problem. If your question is abotu wrapping in a treeview, we don't need much more than a treeview with one or two rows of data that isn't being displayed the way you want. It would also be very beneficial if the example had some hard-coded data, rather than relying on an external file.

Comment: @BryanOakley  thanks for your comment. Sure, I will do that.

Comment: @BryanOakley i have edited my question add minimal reproducible example. Please check it . Thank you.